# Jetty, doFilter method not getting called

Tags: java, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty

I have set up an embedded Jetty server with a filter to add some headers to every request.

```
MainHandler mainHandler = new MainHandler();
        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/application");
        servletContextHandler.setHandler(mainHandler);
        servletContextHandler.setAllowNullPathInfo(true);
        servletContextHandler.addFilter(MyFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.FORWARD));
```

Mainhandler is the class which processes the requests.
The init() method of the filter is called, but not the  doFilter() Method thus my filter is not applied. I tried it with "/application/something".

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't mix `Handlers` and `ServletContextHandler's` like that.

That's not what the `ServletContextHandler.setHandler(Handler)` is for.

Change your `MainHandler` to extend from `HttpServlet` and add it to the `ServletContextHandler.addServlet()`.

Your `MainHandler` is preventing correct dispatch of the request into the `ServletContextHandler`.

This is because `ServletContextHandler.setHandler()` is for the management of things outside of the `ServletContext` and the specific request chain (such as session management, security management, gzip encoding management, request logging management, etc), not for actually processing a request and producing a response within that `ServletContext`.   The `ServletContextHandler.setHandler()` is meant for managing state and scope within an exchange (request, response, inputs, outputs, sessions, security, etc), with all valid implementations being a `ScopedHandler` that is `ServletContext`, `Context`, and `ServletContextHandler` aware.

Comment: Not quite sure why this is the accepted answer. While it may evaluate to true, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Midiman the answer contained enough to answer the question (the MainHandler is the cause for the bad behavior), original answer provided a fix.  Updated answer provides more details (I don't assume people want long details unless asked).

Answer (score -1):

Look at [this](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html#_embedding_servlets) example of the official documentation:

```
package org.eclipse.jetty.embedded;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;

public class MinimalServlets
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        // Create a basic jetty server object that will listen on port 8080.
        // Note that if you set this to port 0 then a randomly available port
        // will be assigned that you can either look in the logs for the port,
        // or programmatically obtain it for use in test cases.
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        // The ServletHandler is a dead simple way to create a context handler
        // that is backed by an instance of a Servlet.
        // This handler then needs to be registered with the Server object.
        ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
        server.setHandler(handler);

        // Passing in the class for the Servlet allows jetty to instantiate an
        // instance of that Servlet and mount it on a given context path.

        // IMPORTANT:
        // This is a raw Servlet, not a Servlet that has been configured
        // through a web.xml @WebServlet annotation, or anything similar.
        handler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/*");

        // Start things up!
        server.start();

        // The use of server.join() the will make the current thread join and
        // wait until the server is done executing.
        // See
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()
        server.join();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        @Override
        protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,
                                                            IOException
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello from HelloServlet</h1>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a `ServletContextHandler`, that's a `ServletHandler`.

Comment: Note: `ServletHandler` is an internal class for `ServletContextHandler` and has no `ServletContext` and as such cannot have anything that needs it (like `Filters`, or sessions, or security, or anything else really).  The above demo only works with 1 `Servlet`, and that's it.